# stty doesn't work

Tags: command-line

I've changed shortcuts for terminal to copy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, paste, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and interrupt the application, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Copy and past works fine but interruption doesn't.The terminal just doesn't react on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> shortcut. So then I should put command `stty intr ^J` for every session to make terminal work properly.

Is there the possibility to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appending `stty intr ^J` to `~/.bashrc` should do it.